# If user modify question and motive should I edit my answer or post another?

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes a user has asked a question with completely different motive and after few conversation in comment user decides to change the question and new question is having a mostly different approach to code. so should I edit my answer or Add another answer to the question?

Comment: Since such kind of edits aren't allowed, the only thing you can do is to flag for a moderator to rollback that edit. Or do nothing and wait until a user with more than 2k reputation comes along.

Comment: And add the following comment to the question "Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference."

Comment: Cross-site dup - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions